# bicycle for a beginner

Tags: road-bike, beginner

I'm a beginner (I bike 10km a day on a BSO MTB, but I guess that doesn't count) to long distance biking. I signed up for a 40km charity bike ride that happens next month. Thought I'd practice for it yesterday and found out my current bike is not up to it.

I'd like to invest in a decent bike (say 500 euros?). Is the BTwin rc 100 road bike any good? Or does anyone have suggestions for a decent bike, that will help me get into long distance biking?

Or should I get an MTB/hybrid?

Comment: Sorry, specific product recomendations are off-topic here.

Comment: 10km/day on your MTB absolutely counts (I have a rule of thumb that a bike commuter cab ride a week's worth of commutes in one event without significant training, though they'll feel it the next day - this holds surprisingly well). This is a good excuse to upgrade, but it's also perfectly sensible on a hybrid, which will be more like a good version of what you're used to. Road bikes feel quite different to ride. I went from your sort of bike to a decent hybrid, and only changed up to a road bike when I was frequently riding 70km days and felt like doing more.

Comment: That's a long winded way of saying don't be discouraged by the fact this is going to be closed as a shopping question - but also think about what you're going to use it for in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You have a good foundation of experience with your current bike. That's a great start toward finding something that you'll really like.
Though we don't recommend products there are things to think about when looking for a bike.
The link Swifty posted in comments is an article with many good thoughts.

Summarizing the thoughts:

1. Think about **what kind of riding you will be doing**, not just on the charity ride but beyond that. There is a range of bikes that are designed for functionality between extreme off road and extreme on road with every flavor in between. The key will be to settle on a type of bike that best fits your need.
2. Comfort - the bike **should fit you and feel comfortable**. If a bike isn't comfortable you are less likely to ride it. It's possible for a really bad fit can injure you.
3. Generally, bike manufacturers carry a line of bikes with a model in each type and price point. Once you have identified the type of bike that fits your need for a particular price comparison shopping becomes easier. It's a matter of comparing similar types of bikes from different manufacturers for a particular price.
4. Visit your local bike shops. You should find people who like to talk about bikes and won't pressure you into buying something. They should encourage you to **test ride different kinds of bikes** so you can gain enough experience to know what feels comfortable to you. If the first bike shop you visit isn't like this try another one.

If you select a new bike based on your type of riding, fit, and feel I'm sure you can find something that will be fun to ride in your price range.